# Stretch Rectangle and Fit Text on Multiple Lines in Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm currently drawing a rectangle under a bitmap using the Canvas in Android. I am using the following code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() + 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
Rect r = new Rect(0, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() + 100);
c.drawRect(r, myPaint);

Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setTextSize(20);
textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
int width = r.width();
int numOfChars = textPaint.breakText(description,true,width,null);
int start = (altText.length()-numOfChars)/2;
c.drawText(description,start,start+numOfChars,r.exactCenterX(),r.exactCenterY(),textPaint);
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

The bitmap draws fine and the rectangle draws directly below it.  The text draws centered inside the rectangle.  My issue is that the text (which varies in length) draws outside the rectangle.  What I would like to happen is have the text skip to a new line when it reaches the end of the rectangle (which is the same width as the bitmap)

This a xkcd comic reader, the alt text is the text I am trying to fit in the rectangle, the image is the comic itself which varies in width (and height)

Comment: give us the context of your code. Where is this code executed? Inside onDraw? Have you checked the possibility to measure the space the text uses and put a break into the best place by yourself?

Comment: My bad, this is inside simply the click of an actionbar event.  I'll try to measure the space when I get home.  I tried multiple different things, except that.